# ClassNotFoundException Mystery

Tags: java, android

Google Play Console is reporting a minute percentage of my users are getting a `ClassNotFoundException` upon app launch. The mystery is, which is the class that cannot be found? Well, the Stacktrace is supposed to state the name, but in these cases it is missing the name. The following is the trace, which is being sent by multiple devices:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4720)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:0)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
```

As you can see, the standard "Didn't find class "xx.yy.zz" message is missing!
Any ideas?

Comment: Some more informations would be nice. API Version. Multidex used etc. As far as I know this was some old dalvik bug, which causes problems on install or first start.

Comment: 80% of affected users are running Android 5., rest are using 5.0, 4.4, 4.3, 4.2. It seems that it happens multiple times to same users.

Answer (score 0):

i just created an account to ask something  so i couldn't help you by a comment:) sorry to make this little hint as an answer.

the last exception without a cause is the interesting one.
my answer despite the data you shared from your project is to look after the line "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:" in your log output, just below that line  goto "BaseDexClassLoader.java:56" by clicking on it, it's the first line in its stack trace ,this line tells you the class and method where the exception with no cause occurred as well as its file and line number, i am pretty sure you will find more clues searching from there as that place is probably caused the main problem.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that I an getting the reports of the crash on the Play Console. I do not get it while debugging. So I cannot get further details.

Comment: oh i see, sorry.
have you had any update recently in your project that includes any API changes? from what you said only users of android 5 and less have this problem, so if you using for example any feature of support library any other 3rd parties, maybe you have to put a android API check before their implementation and keep the previous config for android 5 down to 4,...

Comment: It's not so important for me to patch, as only a few users have the issue. It is more important to me why it's happening.

Comment: I see. in android studio tool bar, Analyze-> inspect code .then select the whole project and run it, if there be any feature that your app is using and it is not compatible with your minimum sdk , it will show a warning. Give it a try if you hadn't yet, maybe that solves the mystery